# UnrealIRCd 4.x.x on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: server, 15.10, irc

Depending on installation and desired configuration, why do I get errors with everything from `c-ares` to `pkg-config` when trying to install unrealIRCd 4.x? I followed the installation steps, so what gives?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the installation, acquiring the following packages should help:

```
build-essential
openssl
libcurl4-openssl-dev
libssl-dev
pkg-config
lib-ares-dev
lib-ares2
```

Now [run the installation script](https://www.unrealircd.org/docs/Installing_from_source).

When prompted by the script for additional configuration options, you may need to add `--with-system-cares`.

Follow the documentation for the rest of it.